# Expand file sysem to entire sd card

Tags: cyanogenmod, file-system, external-sd

I followed very simple instructions

http://liliputing.com/2012/03/how-to-dual-boot-cyanogenmod-7-nook-tablet-os-with-a-microsd-card.html1

for extracting cyanogenmod to an sd card for dual booting on nook.  Works great.  As instructions indicate, file system is only 4gb, even though I used a 16gb sd card.  I've googled all over the place to figure out how to expand the file system to use all avaliable storage.

My laptop is on windows.  the windows disk manager doesnt seem to know how to expand the partitions on the drive (or create a new one on unpartitioned space)

do i need to be running 'nix to manage the file system?

Is there an app on the marketplace that will manage the filesystem?

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I did a pretty good search before posting.

Comment: You'll want Linux to manage EXT partitions for sure (although there ARE Windows tools, they're not native) but I don't know the process to do what you want offhand.

Comment: I've never worked on anything droid before, but why shouldn't there be an app that manages sd partitions?  Isn't there a full linux kernel behind droid?

Comment: Not really, Android is certainly related to Linux but a lot of things are different.  If you can find a native executable to partition the SD card that would be cool.